# What type of arguments does [NSString stringWithFormat] take?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I know that the method `stringWithFormat` is usually used as follows:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", arg1, arg2];
```

My question is, what exactly is the type of the last argument of this method (the one with `...` in the specs).

I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Hi", @"Bob"];
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", array]
```

As you can see one datastructure `array` is holding all of the arguments.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  Is there a way to do this so that I don't have to explicitly list out all of my arguments in the `stringWithFormat` method?

Comment: Your second example should showing an error "More conversions than data arguments" in XCode.

Comment: It takes the types specified in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What type of arguments does `[NSString stringWithFormat]` take?

Whatever type you tell it to do so using its format string.

> My question is, what exactly is the type of the last argument of this method

That's not the last argument. This is a concept called a "variadic function" (or method, in this case). The `...` indicates that the function can take any number of arguments. This is a feature of C, and you can use it by using the types, macros and functions from the C standard library header `<stdarg.h>`. Example: this creates an array with the objects given.

```
- (NSArray *)arrayWithCountAndObjects:(int)count, ...
{
    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        [arr addObject:va_arg(args, id)];
    }
    va_end(args);

    return arr;
}
```

**However,** what you **should** do here is simply joining the items in the array instead of hacking with variadic arguments, because that's unnecessary:

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"Hello", @" ", @"world!"];
NSString *s = [arr componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use string with format, if the array holds strings, then you want to use the array method, componentsJoinedByString:. Just pass @" " as the string if you want a space between the strings.

Answer (score 0):

It takes variable arguments. If you want to look up the type of function, it's called "variadic".

In this specific case, those arguments are determined by the formatting string you specify. `%@` means any cocoa object (inheriting from `NSObject`). `%s` means a c string (null-terminated char array). `%d` means an int, `%f` means a float or double, and so on. There's quite a lot of them (all except `%@` are borrowed from C's `printf` function). You can find full details here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ and here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943

As for your attempt, that's not how it works. You'll just have to split the array up into separate parameters, or use `componentsJoinedByString`, or loop through manually if you need more control. But you could use a single `%@` to display the array in its own format, probably something like `[First Value; Second Value]`.